# Running Live streaming of local user using ffmpeg at Web plateform

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, live-streaming

I am using below command to stream my live desktop screen.

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 1 -loglevel panic -s `xdpyinfo | grep 'dimensions:'|awk '{print $2}'` -i $DISPLAY -qscale 0 -f mpegts udp://192.168.3.151:1111
```

udp://192.168.3.151:1111 - this is my streaming URL

I can see live streaming in the parole media player (in Linux platform), but I can't see this in a cross-network (i.e from windows PC - in the same network)

Is there any web platform so I can see my streaming from anywhere (either windows or linux) just using unique streaming URL or do I need to change my streaming command or method?

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assuming that 192.168.3.151 is your linux machine IP and with mentioned URL (udp://192.168.200.151:1111) you are streaming on port 1111 in your local machine, so it is expected to see this stream only on it.

First of all you can use multicast UDP range ([See more information here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address)) to stream your desktop screen to local LAN like this:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 1 -loglevel panic -s `xdpyinfo | grep 'dimensions:'|awk '{print $2}'` -i $DISPLAY -qscale 0 -f mpegts udp://239.0.0.1:1111
```

So, you can see the stream on other machines in local LAN.

If you want to stream your desktop screen on web, you have to use proper codec like h264 (MP4) and  use a [**media server**](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/media-server/) like **Nginx**, **Wowza** or some like those and stream on it by using this command:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s `xdpyinfo | grep 'dimensions:'|awk '{print $2}'` -framerate 25 -i $DISPLAY -c:v h264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -qscale 0 -f mpegts rtmp://<Media_Server_Address>:1935/live/<stream_name>
```

**Media_Server_Address** is your server domain or IP address. This can be your web server or other server that a media server is installed on it.

**live** is an application that handle live streams. It can have another name but by default it's default name is live.

**stream_name** is An arbitrary name for stream.

In this scenario, you send the stream over **RTMP** on media server and then others can see it by for example **HLS** protocol via a player application like VLC player or via HTML5 video tag in an web page with this URL:

```
http://<Media_Server_Address>:1935/live/<stream_name>/playlist.m3u8
```

**Update:**

This is an example of using Nginx as the media server:

Nginx config:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;

        chunk_size 4000;

    application live {
            live on;
            allow publish all;
            allow play all;
        }

    }
}
```

The FFmpeg command must execute on local PC to stream local PC's desktop to media server:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s `xdpyinfo | grep 'dimensions:'|awk '{print $2}'` -framerate 25 -i $DISPLAY -c:v h264 -preset ultrafast -qscale 0 -f flv rtmp://<Media_Server_Address>:1935/live/localdesktop
```

Now, users can play stream on other PC's using VLC with this URL:

```
rtmp://<Media_Server_Address>/live/localdesktop
```

If HLS playback is required, just the hls config must be added to the Nginx config file. then users can use play hls stream just using this URL using VLC:

```
http://<Media_Server_Address>:1935/live/localdesktop/playlist.m3u8
```

**It is important to note that in this case, the same ffmpeg command must be used.**

Comment: I have installed Nginx server in my media server and also installed RTMP module but when I am trying to stream from my local server with command (suggested by you) I got an error for "-tune" So I have removed that from command and tried to stream with my media server IP. But, streaming is still not working.

So, I tried the below command

"ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 1 -loglevel panic -s `xdpyinfo | grep 'dimensions:'|awk '{print $2}'` -i $DISPLAY -qscale 0 -f mpegts rtmp://<Media_Server_Address>:1935/hls/stream.m3u8"

Now, streaming is working, but video is not loading in the player. Any idea?

Comment: Let me see your nginx.conf

Comment: here i am sharing DOC file.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QUWy5HN8Revk6xVjGMmX1ALFSM32DX7GaavpnPyOm6A/edit

Comment: You have mistakes in streaming and playback. You can use the sample that I added.